# Wordpress ignores custom product archive templates made by Elementor Pro

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, elementor

I made 2 Elementor Pro templates for Woocommerce product archives:

1. Universal template for all product archive (condition is Entire site / Allproduct archives)
   Custom
2. Custom product archive template for specific product category.

My environment is:

- Wordpress 5.8
- Woocommerce 5.4.1
- Elementor + Elementor Pro 3.3.1
- Theme Hello Elementor

Wordpress just ignores all these product archive templates and use product archive embedded into theme.
How to get these custom templates works?

Answer (score 1):

Found - Elementor Pro product archive templates weren’t used because of conflict with Jet Theme Core plugin. Deactivate it and everything works fine.

Hope it can help to someone